# how to reverse unnest_token in R

Tags: r, token, unnest

I would like to know how to reverse the unnest_token function in order to export the tweets and work in python.

Here my dataset

```
ID DATE          TWEETS
1  2020-02-29    people tends stay home reach customer directly bulk email
```

Here what I applied

```
  flood_tweet_messages <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, cleaned_tweets) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, cleaned_tweets) %>%
```

and I got this

```
ID word

1  people
1  tends
1  stay 
1  home
```

How can I reverse the process and go back to the original form of the dataset?
Is it possible to keep the date in the unnested dataset? How?

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(cleaned_tweets = str_flatten(word, " "))`

Comment: It would work If I had the ID column in the df dataset, but I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Then how would you know which words belong to which text?

Comment: Ok, I did it. It was stupid to fix. Your code works great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem!

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(cleaned_tweets = str_flatten(word, " "))
```

Thanks to the user @Phil